# Can I use @Async annotation with Grails

Tags: java, spring, grails, concurrency

As per the following spring doc [link](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/scheduling.html) I can use **@Async** annotation to make a method call asynchronous. Can I use this facility in Grails from a java src file that I have?

**[Update]**
This is my java(netty) socket handler class which receives the socket packet.
public class DefaultHandler extends SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler {

```
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DefaultHandler.class);

private AggregateSocketData aggregateSocketData;

@Override
public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e)
        throws Exception {
    LOG.trace("In messageRecieved method with event: {}",e);
    IEvent event = Events.dataInEvent(e.getMessage());
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
    aggregateSocketData.receiveSocketData(event);
}


@Override
public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ExceptionEvent e)
        throws Exception {
    LOG.error("Exception occurred in Default Handler: " ,e.getCause());
}

public AggregateSocketData getAggregateSocketData() {
    return aggregateSocketData;
}

public void setAggregateSocketData(AggregateSocketData aggregateSocketData) {
    this.aggregateSocketData = aggregateSocketData;
}
```

}

I have made it a bean in grails- conf - resources.xml

```
<bean id="defaultECM1240Handler" class="com.appcapture.buildingmgr.netty.DefaultHandler"
        scope="prototype">
        <property name="aggregateSocketData" ref="binaryDataAggregatorService"></property>
</bean>
```

And this is my grails service class whose method I have annotated with @Async

class BinaryDataAggregatorService implements AggregateSocketData {

```
def rawDataService
static transactional = true

@Async
void receiveSocketData(IEvent event) {
    println Thread.currentThread().name
    log.debug("Going to decode netty packet in receiveSocketData");
    Map decodedPacket = decodePacket((INettyPacket)event.getSource())
    def rawData = saveRawData (decodedPacket);
    log.debug ("Saved raw data, id: ${rawData?.id}")
    rawDataService.saveHTTPData(decodedPacket);
}
```

}

**[Update 2]** Here is the stack trace for the method call.
Here is the stack. BinaryDataAggregatorService.receiveSocketData(INettyPacket) line: 20
BinaryDataAggregatorService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$82489f62.invoke(int, Object, Object[]) line: not available
MethodProxy.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 149
Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint() line: 688
Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation(ReflectiveMethodInvocation).proceed() line: 150
TransactionInterceptor.invoke(MethodInvocation) line: 110
Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation(ReflectiveMethodInvocation).proceed() line: 172
Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Object, Method, Object[], MethodProxy) line: 621
BinaryDataAggregatorService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$1c96985c.receiveSocketData(INettyPacket) line: not available
DefaultHandler.handlePacket(INettyPacket) line: 50

**[Update 3]**
The grails stack trace on setting the task:annotation-driven element.

```
011-05-26 17:38:03,109 [main] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing bootstraps: Error creating bean with name 'defaultECM1240Handler' defined in URL [file:./grails-app/conf/spring/resources.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'binaryDataAggregatorService' while setting bean property 'aggregateSocketData'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'binaryDataAggregatorService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class $Proxy12]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class $Proxy12
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultECM1240Handler' defined in URL [file:./grails-app/conf/spring/resources.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'binaryDataAggregatorService' while setting bean property 'aggregateSocketData'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'binaryDataAggregatorService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class $Proxy12]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class $Proxy12
```

Thanks,
Abraham

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a spring bean - yes, you can. For that you have to annotate it with `@Service` and have a `<context:component-scan base-package="com.foo.bar" />`

But to make it easier, you can use a groovy class placed in the `grails-app/services` - it will be a spring bean automatically

In order to make `@Async` work, you need `<task:annotation-driven/>` in the xml config.

Comment: I added the annotation to a service class, but on debugging I could not see that another thread had been created. Is there some other configuration I need to provide?

Comment: not that I know of. Try printing the current thread id to see if they are the same. And - how do you obtain the instance of the java class?

Comment: I did not add the annotation to Java class, instead I added it to a grails service method. Since it is spring bean by default I thought it will work. When I printed it, I got the same thread name.

Comment: well, it looks fine to me (apart from scope="prototype") .. check if there is a proxy around your groovy service (put a breakpoint and see the stacktrace)

Comment: The prototype is fine, since I create the bean using lookup-method in Spring. I think there is a aop proxy around my service. I have updated the stack in the q.

Comment: Hmmm... Should I declare some pool/Taskscheduler or something in Spring config?. Thanks for looking into this patiently!

Comment: This does not work with Grails...:( When I add the <task:annotation-driven /> with the corresponding schema declaration, the grails service bean lookup fails -> Cannot resolve reference to bean 'binaryDataAggregatorService' while setting bean property 'aggregateSocketData'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:

Comment: Without the <task:annotation-driven /> element, the Grails service bean lookup happens without any issue.

Comment: what is the root cause? Perhaps you are missing some spring jar?

Comment: Looks like the aop proxy wrapping is running into issue. I have provided the stack trace. Note: I am having cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar in my grails lib folder. Will this cause an issue?

Comment: You must not have `final` classes.

Comment: I dont have final classes and I made all my Grails service classes to be public. I also tried adding component scan of the service package, all to no effect...:(

Answer (score 1):

I found this while trying to do the same thing.  I haven't tried it yet, but maybe it will work.

https://gist.github.com/tux2323/2758723

ETA:

I've modified my Resources.groovy file to match what I found here (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/scheduling.html):

```
        xmlns task:"http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
        task.'annotation-driven'('executor':'myExecutor')
        task.'executor'('id':'myExecutor', 'pool-size':'5')
```

My code in the @Async annotation is still using the same thread as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

I've followed step from Jason H answer and it's really help me solve the issue on setting @Async for my service.

```
xmlns task:"http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
task.'annotation-driven'('executor':'myUploadExecutor', 'proxy-target-class':true, 'mode':'proxy')
task.'executor'('id':'myUploadExecutor', 'pool-size':'5')
```

I've add this code in my resources.groovy then you can start using @Async in your code (dont  forget to import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async in you class),
without ('proxy-target-class':true, 'mode':'proxy') you will get an error java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy is thrown when casting your "Service name".

In my case i'm using @Async running on different thread to add something into DB and if you are using @gorm.AuditStamp for your domain, Spring Security context didnt bound to new thread , you will get createdBy and updatedBy NULL .

To solve this issue i've add :
`SecurityContextHolder.setStrategyName(SecurityContextHolder.MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL)`  in my BootStrap.groovy on init .

For more information check out this site: 
http://www.ogrigas.eu/spring/2010/04/inherit-spring-security-context-in-child-threads